# How to connect to a Mac with Apple Remote Desktop over internet with IP address?

Tags: remote-desktop, apple-remote-desktop

I am trying to connect to my friends mac over the internet. His mac is sitting behind his home router. I entered his IP address in the Network scanner and can't see anything. His mac is configured to control remotely in system preferences. I searched online and found that it can done using iCloud back to my Mac. But the catch is it has to be the same iCloud account. Is there any way around this?

Comment: You need to open/forward the VNC ports on the router/firewall at the remote location.  If you’re not sure how to do this, maybe something like TeamViewer would be a better solution

Comment: Team viewer is not working anymore. It disconnects every 5 mins thinking I am using it for commercial use. Could not fix it.

Comment: You mean port forwarding?

Comment: Yes - port forwarding is one way to do it. This will obviously have to be done on your friend's router. Is your friend's IP address a private IP address (i.e. only used on a LAN), or is it a public/routable IP address?

Comment: @Seamus He is using a router. His MacBook IP address is within the router like 192.168.1.150 And he has a public ip.

Comment: What do you mean "Team Viewer is not working anymore."  I used it just yesterday to connect to a friends computer and it worked perfectly.

Comment: @Allan People have been reporting that it says “Commercial use detected” even though they are using it for personal use. I tried a couple of solutions but didn’t work.

Comment: If that's the case, you need to set up port forwarding on your (friend's) router/firewall to allow for the VNC protocol to pass through.  Unfortunately, that's off topic here.

Comment: @Allan Alright. I can’t believe that ARD doesn’t have a simple function like connecting using IP address. I wish it worked like teamviewer.

Comment: ARD and VNC use a direct connection, Team Viewer connects in the cloud.  To use *any* direct connection, you **must** forward the ports on your router.

Comment: @Allan Thank you. Will try the port forwarding.